# FFMPEG Concat fast video .ts to .mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

How Can I Optimization this concat? I'm trying concat two movies with 30 minutes in one with 1 hour in .mp4. Look at my example below:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:E:\Servico\Band\Videos\video-07-10-2015_10-32-21.ts|E:\Servico\Band\Videos\video-07-10-2015_09-43-22.ts " -preset ultrafast  E:\Servico\Band\Videos\Temp\out.mp4
```

Comment: It doesn't get much faster than that.  In any case, this question is off-topic here.  Post on SuperUser.com instead.

Comment: Make sure (y)asm isn't disabled. You didn't provide the complete console output, so there is no way to tell.

Comment: Is There other format to save and concat to a file .mp4 ?